# Lightbox 2 Image Title Not Always Showing

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm having a slight issue on my personal site where I'm using Lightbox 2.

I'm able to get the images and gallery up and running no problem, however in certain cases when I click on the picture links from my site the Titles do not load. It seems totally random, and not associated with any of the pictures. Sometimes they will show up, and other times not.

The page this is happening on is [here](http://www.marcusstoll.com/). In the second paragraph, first sentence, are the links to the images through the words "hiker" "skier" "golfer" "traveller" and "adventurer".

Any help on what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated. Minor issue, but frustrating me nonetheless.

Thanks,
Marcus